# Tensorflow CTC loss: ctc_merge_repeated parameter

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, ocr

I'm using Tensorflow 1.0 and its CTC loss [1].
When training, I sometimes get the "No valid path found." warning (which harms learning). It is **not** due to a high learning rate as sometimes reported by other Tensorflow users.

After analyzing it a bit, I found the pattern that causes this warning:

- feeding an input sequence into the ctc_loss with length *seqLen*
- feeding a label with *labelLen* characters
- label has *numRepeatedChars* repeated chars in it, where I count "ab" as 0, "aa" as 1, "aaa" as 2 and so on
- warning occurs, when: *seqLen* - *labelLen* < *numRepeatedChars*

Three examples:

- Ex.1: label="abb", len(label)=3, len(inputSequence)=3 => (3-3=0)<1 is true --> warning
- Ex.2: label="abb", len(label)=3, len(inputSequence)=4 => (4-3=1)<1 is false --> no warning
- Ex.3: label="bbb", len(label)=3, len(inputSequence)=4 => (4-3=1)<2 is true --> warning

When I now set the ctc_loss parameter ctc_merge_repeated=False, then the warning disappears.

Three questions:

- Q1: why is there a warning when repeated chars occur? I thought, as long as the input sequence is not shorter than the target labelling, there is no problem. And when repeated chars are merged in the label, then it gets even shorter, therefore the condition that the input sequence is not shorter still holds.
- Q2: why does the ctc_loss in its default settings produce this warning? Repeated chars are common in the domains CTCs are used such as handwritten text recognition (HTR)
- Q3: what settings should I use when doing HTR? Of course labels can have repeated chars. Therefore ctc_merge_repeated=False would make sense. Any suggestions?

Python program to reproduce warning:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def createGraph():
    tinputs=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [100, 1, 65]) # max 100 time steps, 1 batch element, 64+1 classes
    tlabels=tf.SparseTensor(tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[None,2]) , tf.placeholder(tf.int32,[None]), tf.placeholder(tf.int64,[2])) # labels
    tseqLen=tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None]) # list of sequence length in batch
    tloss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.ctc_loss(labels=tlabels, inputs=tinputs, sequence_length=tseqLen, ctc_merge_repeated=True)) # ctc loss
    return (tinputs, tlabels, tseqLen, tloss)

def getNextBatch(nc): # next batch with given number of chars in label
    indices=[[0,i] for i in range(nc)]
    values=[i%65 for i in range(nc)]
    values[0]=0
    values[1]=0 # TODO: (un)comment this to trigger warning
    shape=[1, nc]
    labels=tf.SparseTensorValue(indices, values, shape)
    seqLen=[nc]
    inputs=np.random.rand(100, 1, 65)
    return (labels, inputs, seqLen) 


(tinputs, tlabels, tseqLen, tloss)=createGraph()

sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

nc=3 # number of chars in label
print('next batch with 1 element has label len='+str(nc))
(labels, inputs, seqLen)=getNextBatch(nc)
res=sess.run([tloss], { tlabels: labels, tinputs:inputs, tseqLen:seqLen } )
```

This is the C++ Tensorflow code [2] where the warning comes from:

```
// It is possible that no valid path is found if the activations for the
// targets are zero.
if (log_p_z_x == kLogZero) {
    LOG(WARNING) << "No valid path found.";
    dy_b = y;
    return;
}
```

[1] https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/nn/ctc_loss

[2] https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/util/ctc/ctc_loss_calculator.cc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, got it, that's not a bug, that's just how CTC works: let's take an example for which the warning occurs: length of input sequence is 2, labelling is "aa" (also length 2).

Now the shortest path which yields "aa" is a->blank->a (length 3). 
But for a labelling "ab", the shortest path is a->b (length 2).
That shows why for repeated labels like in "aa" the input sequence must be longer. Its simply the way how repeated labels get encoded in the CTC by inserting blanks.

Label repeatings therefore decrease the maximum length of an allowed labelling when fixing the input size.